# Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map or do not find Browserslist config

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

> Witout `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map or do not
>   find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to
>   prevent this warning

ionic3 project, when I running `ionic corodva bulid ios --prod` showing this warning for me.

**ionic info**

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.7
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    Node       : v6.11.3
    npm        : 3.10.10 
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

UPDATE:

I tried to update my npm to 5.5.1 and node to 8.6.0, but still showing.

Comment: It is just a warning.This is an open bug in [Ionic Github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13763).Also an open pull request [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/pull/1364).

Comment: @SurajRao Thanks for reply.. so it will not change to error?

Comment: It wont cause any issues.. but you can do a workaround like https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/pull/1364#issuecomment-357985585 . Its the same change as the pull request. Or you could do https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13763#issuecomment-356281696

Comment: Thanks a lot, https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/pull/1364#issuecomment-357985585 this one is working for me now.

Comment: I post it as a answer, thanks @SurajRao

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Finally, this warning solved. Thanks to ***Suraj Rao***

First find `sass.js` file under `/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/sass.js.`
inside search `var postcssOptions` and add `from: undefined,`

Finally should be like this:

```
var postcssOptions = {
            from: undefined,
            to: path_1.basename(sassConfig.outFile),
            map: autoPrefixerMapOptions
        };
```

Reference： [workaround](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/pull/1364#issuecomment-357985585).

Answer (score 18):

For whoever directly used PostCSS and met this issue then came here,
Change your

```
postcss( any_plugins ).process( css )
```

to

```
postcss( any_plugins ).process( css, { from: undefined } )
```

can fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding `map: { inline: false }` solved my problem.